Почему эта программа не определяет симметричную последовательность?
Вот сама задача:
Последовательность чисел назовём симметричной, если она одинаково читается как слева направо, так и справа налево. Например, следующие последовательности являются симметричными:
1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1
1 2 1 2 2 1 2 1
Вашей программе будет дана последовательность чисел. Требуется определить, какое минимальное количество и каких чисел надо приписать в конец этой последовательности, чтобы она стала симметричной.
Формат ввода: сначала вводится число N(1 ≤ N ≤ 100), далее идет N чисел-элементы этой последовательности, натуральные числа от 1 до 9.
Решаю задание по симметричной последовательности. Один из закрытых тестов выдает отрицательный ответ. Тк он закрытый, данные я получить не могу. Вот сам код, на большинстве тестов выдает правильный ответ:
x = int(input())
nums = list(map(int, input().split()))

if nums == nums[::-1]:
    print(0)
else:
    y = 1
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if nums[-i - 1] == nums[-i - 2]:
            y += 1
        else:
            break
    nums_reverse = nums[:-y]
    print(len(nums_reverse))
    for i in nums_reverse[::-1]:
        print(i, end=" ")

Если возможно, прошу не писать сам код, а просто обьяснить в чем ошибка.

Что такое "симметричная последовательность"? Какой должен быть ответ для разных последовательностей?

Какого размера могут быть последовательности? Ваша ошибка здесь if nums[-i - 1] == nums[-i - 2]: - конец строки не обязан состоять из одинаковых элементов

Для последовательности 1 2 3 2 вы выдаёте 3, 3 2 1. Правильный ответ - 1, 1.

Для небольших длин подойдёт простой алгоритм - мы поочерёдно проверяем, является ли суффикс строки длиной n, n-1, n-2..1 палиндромом. Для полной длины n вы уже проверяете, можно делать то же самое с nums[i:].
Про дописывание перевернутого  префикса вы уже знаете (nums_reverse).
